# doing check internet connection on another thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

When I press login button, the app freezes for a while because it checks internet connection on the main thread. how to do it in the background thread or new thread and what is the difference between them (Background thread and another new Thread).

my internet check function :

```
public Boolean isOnline() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
        return (exitValue == 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check the internet connection is user data is on? Or if data is actually flowing?

Comment: `the app freezes for a while because it checks internet connection on the main thread`. Internet can only be checked from a different thread than the main thread. Your app freezes because of the `ipProcess.waitFor();`

Comment: You better put all in a thread and if the thread is done you enable the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to execute a `PING` command to check if you have a real internet connection and not just network connection. In that case, its using a Network and so you will end up with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

One of the way you can implement this is by creating a callback method that returns the result of the `PING` from the background thread.

Below **pseudo** code reiterates what I mean:

```
interface ResultCallback {
   void onComplete(boolean result);
}

class checkInternet extend AsyncTask<., ., Boolean> {
  ResultCallback callback;
  public static checkInternet(ResultCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  void doInBackGround() {
     return isOnline();
  }

  onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    callback.onComplete(result);
  }
}
```

Have a function

```
void performCheckOnInternet(ResultCallback callback) {
    new checkInternet(callback).execute();
  }
```

Now, you can call this async task like:

```
performCheckOnInternet(new ResultCallback {
    void onComplete(boolean result) {
       //do your stuff here 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that this will work, but it's quite complicated and I can't apply all that code to all my activites (Login, Signup and Reset Password activites will check for internet). can't you give me a short way to check internet connection in the background thread ?

Comment: What library do you use for network layer? Retrofit2?HttpURLConnection? Incase if you are using Retrofit2, there is a easy way you can handle this. if there is no internet connection, it's onFailure method get calls immediate, and there you could check the exception type to check further if your there was a network outage.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to check if data is actually flowing? If not, you can use this (simpler) apporach:

```
public static boolean hasInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```